# Once compiled, can a program hypothetically run without ever calling eval?

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp, eval

I'm in the process of learning how Clojure works and I'm wondering if it would be possible (just for the sake of understanding how Clojure and Lisps dialects do work in general) to compile a Clojure program and then to run it while "forbidding" the use of *eval*.

Note that I'm not asking if it would be technically possible to, say, hotpatch a running Clojure program so that once compiled a Clojure program would throw an exception should *eval* ever be called.

What I'm asking is that *if* it is technically possible to forbid the use of *eval*, would most Clojure programs not using a REPL and not specifically *eval* still work?

Or are the default / built-in APIs / macros / functions using *eval* under the hood at runtime?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of Clojure specifically, but [SICP 4.1](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1) describes the architecture of Lisp interpreters in general. One of its two main functions is called `eval`, but this could be renamed and need not be visible to the code that it is running for that code to function.

Comment: Are you talking about forbidding eval in your code? What about bracketing eval inside a macro, and enabling/disabling it based on a flag of some sort?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: well if I could totally disable *read* and *eval* on the whim of a flag of some sort, I'd be very happy... But at this point it's mostly to understand a bit better how Clojure / Lisps do work. : )

Answer (score 10):

`eval` is what brings the interactive programming to Clojure (and Lisps). You don't need eval once you have compiled Clojure code to jvm byte code (which doesn't use eval function call anywhere), or other Lisp dialects to their targeted runtime (mostly native code).

`eval` main purpose in an application would be to generate code at runtime and execute it, basically it would allow to create "runtime macros", which isn't what the core API of the language need to do for what it does.

Comment: +1 ok that is very nice... And it's the same for *read* right? I mean: if you're not specifically using *read* then the compiled JVM bytecode doesn't use *read* calls anywhere?

Comment: @CedricMartin It shouldn't, as long as it's not an interpreted Lisp dialect. And Clojure isn't.

Comment: @Ankur: lots of bad-intentioned people like the ones creating botnets of pirated machines also like, for example, JavaScript's *eval* a lot.  There just seems to be an endless number of exploits allowing to gain root/admin rights based on (poor) sites allowing code injection through the use of *eval* ; )    So you're far from the only one who likes *eval* to be available at runtime : )

Comment: @Ankur: and I know I can *"simply just not use neither read nor eval"* but what if some poor API uses it under the hood and I get affected by using this API?  What if a default/built-in API is exposing it?  I simply want to better understand what is going on.  Then why in Common Lisp is it adviced to bind READ-EVAL to *nil* and *READTABLE* to your own table to be sure input is sanitized / not-executed?  Is there really *"nothing to see here, move along"*?  Or is it just a case of *"we've not been hacked yet, but it shall come"* ?

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question a long time ago and I'm answering my own question because additional information came up and exploits came up too and the other question do *not* adress correctly the issue.

Basically the default read functions are unsafe.

There has been heated discussion on the Clojure groups in 2013 after all the Ruby exploits (where people suddenly felt concerned by the security implications) regarding this issue, in a thread of discussion called:

> "*read-eval* defaulting to false"

The Clojure docs themselves clearly states that:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read

```
;; WARNING: You SHOULD NOT use clojure.core/read or
;; clojure.core/read-string to read data from untrusted sources.  They
;; were designed only for reading Clojure code and data from trusted
;; sources
```

Note that even setting *read-eval* to *false* is not sufficient (at least not up until at least Clojure 1.5) because some Java constructors can be forced to be called and have side-effect by carefully crafting malicious inputs.

This is explained in detail in a blog entry called: *"Clojure's Reader is Unsafe"*

http://www.learningclojure.com/2013/02/clojures-reader-is-unsafe.html

Long story short: use something else, like `clojure.edn`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably fair to say that:

- *most* uses of `eval` are done either interactively (at the REPL) or at compile time (e.g. during expansion and execution of macros)
- *some* uses of eval happen in regular code. It can be a useful trick, e.g. when executing dynamically generated mathematical formulae in a spreadsheet program.

Because of the second reason, if you forbade the use of eval globally, you would break a lot of code / libraries at runtime even if everything was already compiled.